# Creating а custom routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

In my application I want to create a custom routing. I would like when it that when I enter a URL like `www.mydomainname.com/stringdata` to trigger `DefaultAction`:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DefaultAction(string stringdata)
{
   ...
}
```

I tried to do this using `app.UseMvc` extension:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
      name: null,
      template: "{stringdata}",
      defaults: new { controller = "DefaultController", action = "DefaultAction" });
});
```

But I read that I should use `endpoints.MapControllerRoute()` instead of `app.UseMvc()`.

Is it possible to create this route using `endpoints.MapControllerRoute()`?

Comment: This post needs more details and clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just apply RouteAttribute `[Route("{stringdata}")]` to the action method:

```cs
[Route("{stringdata}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DefaultAction(string stringdata)
{
   ...
}
```

It will processed as required with the `Configure()` method generated by the standard template, without calling the `MapControllerRoute()`:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

For more information, including how to use the `MapControllerRoute()` (in case it will be required) see [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0)